Aligning a DataTable cell to be at top rather than centered
I have a DataTable widget that looks as follows:

Notice the vertical alignment of the cell in column "col1".  It is centered.  I would like the vertical alignment to be "start" so that the values shows at the top of the cell.  Unfortunately I can't seem to find any way to do this.
Here is my code fragment illustrating the test environment:
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
      DataTable(
        dataRowMaxHeight: double.infinity,
        columns: const [
          DataColumn(label: Text("col1")),
          DataColumn(label: Text("col2"))
        ],
        rows: const [
          DataRow(cells: [
            DataCell(Text("Col1 Value")),
            DataCell(Column(children: [
              Text("Col2 Value1"),
              Text("Col2 Value2"),
              Text("Col2 Value3"),
              Text("Col2 Value4")
            ])),
          ])
        ],
      )
    ]));
  }

based on the above, what might I do to have the "Col1 Value" widget positioned at the top of the table cell rather than centered in its middle position?
Many thanks in advance.

I think DataCell  takes center alignment. I have try many try but not get exact solution with start alignment.
